# How can I install Lua on macOS Monterey, without admin powers and terminal access? (I have the vscose Terminal available)

Tags: terminal, lua, sudo, macos-monterey

I have this school M1 MacBook Air, without admin rights or terminal access. They let me install a few things but only from their list of programs, like vscose and python. I'm trying to install Lua to get started with it, but facing problems with the installation.

I downloaded the source, but being unable to use terminal I thought I will use vscode's terminal. I opened the decompressed file and ran "make", but I get this error: "unable to load libxcrun (dlopen(/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib, 0x0005): tried: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libxcrun.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64), need (arm64e))))." The solutions online all use sudo commands, which I can't use (obviously). So, my questions is, any way to do this ? please?

Comment: if you cannot do something due to user rights, get in touch with your admin. according to the error you're trying to build Lua for the wrong processor architecture.

Answer (score 0):

- Download lua: http://www.lua.org/download.html
- Extract it: e.g. `tar -xzvf lua-5.4.4.tar.gz; cd lua-5.4.4`
- Where is your home directory? `pwd` Let us assume `/Users/swisscookieman`.
- Make a lua directory: `mkdir /Users/swisscookieman/lua`.
- Edit the `Makefile` to change the line `INSTALL_TOP= /usr/local` to that directory.
- For example: `INSTALL_TOP= /Users/swisscookieman/lua`.
- Run `make macosx && make install` to compile and install.

Make sure to specify `/Users/swisscookieman/lua/bin` in your PATH variable to see the binary or always use the whole path (e.g. `/Users/swisscookieman/lua/bin/lua`).